# Automating Account updates - Correct rows are not showing up - SQL/SNOWFLAKE/MYSQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following table that contains accounts and owners. I would like to get the owner with its maximum end date in case he appears simultaneously. However, if same owner appears after an account was passed to some other owner in between then it's end date should not be touched and should be added together:

```
create table table_acc( acc int, owner_id  int, start_date date,  end_date date);

insert into table_acc values (    1,         101,            '2021-05-10 ',        '2021-05-10');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-05-10',         '2021-05-14');
insert into table_acc values (    1,         102,            '2021-05-14',         '2100-01-01');
```

Table:

```
   acc     owner_id          start_date           end_date        
    1         101            2021-05-10         2021-05-10      
    1         102            2021-05-10         2021-05-14
    1         102            2021-05-14         2021-05-19       
    1         101            2021-05-19         2022-01-01
```

Output should be :

```
    acc     owner_id          start_date         end_date        
    1         101            2021-05-10         2021-05-10      
    1         102            2021-05-10         2021-05-19       
    1         101            2021-05-19         2022-01-01
```

I am using this code but it's NOT giving the correct rows and is giving the results as follows:

```
   acc     owner_id          start_date             end_date            
    1         102            2021-05-10         2021-05-19       
    1         101            2021-05-10         2022-01-01
```

here somehow it's taking maximum from each owner id even though owner 1 should appear with two different rows as it didn't become an owner.

I am using the code as below:

```
select 
acc,
owner_id,
min(start_date),
max(end_date)
from (
select *,
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc order by start_date))-
(dense_rank() over (partition by acc,owner_id order by start_date)) rank_ from table_acc
) t
group by 1,2, rank_
order by 1,3
```

You can run the code and database from here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=99ca12c51278819a7f69d4fa8552d11a

Comment: @Strawberry yes I had to add it separately since this one has a separate data set

Comment: @Strawberry did you figure the issue already ?

Comment: @Strawberry please check again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233007/discussion-between-trillion-and-strawberry).

Comment: is it mysql or snowflake ? remove unrelated database tag

Comment: @eshirvana it's snowflake but i believe the syntax is similar for such case

Answer (score 0):

here is one way :

```
select acc , owner_id , min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date 
from (
select * , dense_rank() over (partition by acc, owner_id , case when start_date = prev_end_Date then 1 else 0 end order by start_date ) 
from (select * , LAG(end_date) over (partition by acc, owner_id order by start_date) prev_end_Date
from table_acc ) t
) t 
group by acc , owner_id
```

Comment: @trillion what does "doesn't work" mean ? gives you error? doesn't return what you want? if not show me what it returns and what you want

Comment: the code should work with both of the scenarios that are explained above. You can test your code here and observe the output Case 1 : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=897589554e264da338f939cf7fb52c7a        Case 2: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=897589554e264da338f939cf7fb52c7a With your code the Case 1 is not working. The code should be dynamic and should work with both cases. My code works fine with Case 1 And not Case 2. In your case it only works with Case 2